# MVC Controller not parsing Ajax Request Correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have an MVC .NET 4.5 application using an Ajax request with JSON to hit the MVC controller on server side. The function in the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SomeFunction(int int1, List<int> listOfInts, int int2)
    {
        someOtherFunction(int1, listOfInts, int2);
    }
```

and the ajax request looks like this:

```
actionData = {
            int1: 1,
            int2: 2,
            listOfInts: list
        }
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: actionURL,
        data: JSON.stringify(actionData),
        traditional: true,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: functionIfSuccessful() },
        error: functionIfNotSuccessful() }
    });
```

If I look at the request in Fiddler the JSON ojbect being passed has the format:

```
int1=1
int2=2
listOfInts=[1,2]
```

The problem is when the function in the MVC controller is hit, the `int1` and `int2` properties are set correctly from the request but the `listOfInts` parameter is empty. I have tried changing it to use a primitive array instead of a List object aswell but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Have you tried having a class that will wrap int1, int2, and listOfInts?

Comment: Like a DTO? I have been contemplating it. But have not done it yet. I would like to avoid it if I could because this is the only place in my site that the DTO would be used. I prefer not to make one for a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. This issue was being caused by something outside of the code provided. The javascript that was building the list of integers should not have been adding the brackets to the ends. Removed those and it worked like a charm.